# UITableView show all rows and no scroll

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have a UITableView with dynamic cells. I would like to disable the scroll and show all rows. My aim is to have is to have a scroll view that contains the tableview and additional views, but i want the parent scroll view get its content size from all of its child elements, including the UITableView.

This is what I have tried so far;

```
self.tableView.scrollEnabled = false
var frame = self.tableView.frame
frame.size.height = self.tableView.contentSize.height
self.tableView.frame = frame
```

With this, I can disable the scroll but not all rows are displayed.

I cannot seem to find a way to force the UITableView to display all of its cells, is it possible? Is there an alternative way that I should be approaching the design?

Comment: Autolayout is disable?Cause if your autolayout is enable from Interface builder you can not change frame through coding  like this

Comment: are you returning values for headerHeights, rowHeights so that it all will fit?  If the table can't scroll and you want to see all of its content then you'll have to make the content small enough to fit inside the static space that you provide